# viewmodel parameter into json for ajax request

Tags: c#, jquery, razor, asp.net-core-2.1

In my `Net Core 2.1 MVC` project I have a viewmodel parameter userID, that I want to assign to a JQuery variable after the page loads. The ID is not displayed anywhere on the page.
So far, this doesn't seem to work:

View:

```
@{int userID = Model.ID;}
// rest of html page.
@section scripts {
    <script src="~/AssigntoVariable.js"></script>
}
```

AssignToVariable.js

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
        var json = userID;
        console.log(json);
        // removed further code
```

When I run this, I receive a 'UserID not defined' error, obviously.
How can I put the userID parameter from my viewmodel directly in a JQuery script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access viewmodel parameter `ID` as `userID` on client-side like:

```
@section scripts {    
    <script type="text/javascript">
        var userID = @(Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model.ID))); 

        // You can now access userID here
        console.log(userID);
    </script>
    <script src="~/AssigntoVariable.js"></script>
}
```

and now you can also access `userID` in `AssignToVariable.js` like:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
   var json = userID;
   console.log(json);
});
```

Please note that you don't need to use

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $(function () {
```

both of them in `AssignToVariable.js` file, as `$(function () {` is just a shorthand for [`$(document).ready(function () {`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/document-ready/). Please use either one of them.